# Firebase Auth Email Verifications not being sent to certain email providers (iCloud, possibly others)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a new site in production, using Firebase Auth. Email verifications are triggering successfully for the vast majority of people.

However, they are NOT triggering for people with @icloud.com email addresses. I have verified this by creating an iCloud email address and triggering the email verification. Nothing comes through.

The email DOES come through for my various @gmail.com addresses.

There may be other email providers this is *also* failing for. There are a number of users with unverified email addresses, particularly with uncommon domains like @y7mail.com, or custom domains (so I can't tell what provider they're on).

I cannot find any logs for this service, so I can't see why it's failing. I'm really at a loss as to what to do. Has anyone run into this issue, or can provide any clues?

Comment: You should contact Firebase support directly with your observations.  There's nothing Stack Overflow can do to resolve missing emails from Firebase Auth. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Thanks Doug. I was hoping someone else had encountered this problem and had an obvious solution I was missing. I will contact Firebase.